# Heroku Deploy errror "missing required flag"

Tags: heroku

I'm deploying heroku with github but I'm getting some errors. these are Heroku CLI errors. but I'm deploy with github ?

[image: Heroku error]

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you deployed—you're trying to run a Heroku CLI command (`heroku logs`). When you do that, Heroku needs to know which app to run against. Sometimes it can infer that (see the last two dupes) but if it can't, you need to tell it (see the first three dupes).